# Java Servlet POST data to a third party without a proxy

Tags: java, forms, servlets, file-upload, apache-httpclient-4.x

We have some forms that I need to handle and then post to a 3rd party.  I made a servlet to do this using Apache HTTPClient.  Which works pretty good.  I needed it to handle both multipart encoded requests with files and non-multipart encoded requests as well so this is what I whipped up and mapped it to /ProcessForm:

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    String errorPage = "/";
    URLEncoder encoder = new URLEncoder();
    MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

    // See what kinda request we have
    if(ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request)) {
        // Handle the multi-part data
        FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
        ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);

        try {
            List<FileItem> items = upload.parseRequest(request);
            for(FileItem item : items) {
                if(item.isFormField()) {
                    // Parse non-file field
                    String name = item.getFieldName();
                    String val = item.getString();
                    entity.addPart(name, new StringBody(val));
                } else {
                    // Parse file-field
                    String fieldName = item.getFieldName();
                        String fileName = item.getName();
                    byte[] data = item.get();
                    ContentBody fileBody = new ByteArrayBody(data, fileName);
                    entity.addPart(fieldName, fileBody);
                }
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            Logger.error(this, "Exception Parsing Form", e);
            response.sendRedirect(errorPage);
            return;
        }
    } else {
        // Handle a non-multipart form
        Enumeration<String> parameterNames = request.getParameterNames();
        for (; parameterNames.hasMoreElements();) {
            String name = parameterNames.nextElement();
            String[] vals = request.getParameterValues(name);
            for(String val : vals){
                entity.addPart(name, new StringBody(val));
            }
        }
    } 

    // DO SOME PROCESSING WITH THE DATA ...

    String actionPath = "https://some-third-party-site.com";

    // Post the data to the action Path
    DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    httpclient.setRedirectStrategy(new DefaultRedirectStrategy() {
            public boolean isRedirected(HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response, HttpContext context)  {
            boolean isRedirect=false;
            try {
                isRedirect = super.isRedirected(request, response, context);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Logger.debug(this,"Some Exception checking for redirect",e);
            }
            if (!isRedirect) {
                int responseCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
                if (responseCode == 301 || responseCode == 302) return true;
            }
            return isRedirect;
        }
        });
    ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(actionPath);
    httpPost.getParams().setParameter("http.protocol.handle-redirects",true);
    httpPost.setEntity(entity);
    String resp = "";
    try {
        resp = httpclient.execute(httpPost, responseHandler);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        Logger.error(this, "Exception Posting Form", e);                
        httpPost.releaseConnection();               
        response.sendRedirect(errorPage);
        return;
    }

    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.write(resp);
    out.flush();

    out.close();
    httpPost.releaseConnection();
    return;
}
```

This works great - the problem is that the request to the third party is "proxied" by my servlet and the powers that be do not like this.  They do not want the url in the end to be https://our-site.com/ProcessForm they want it to be https://the-third-party-site.com/whatever.

I've been trying to figure out how to do this and so far I have not come up with a way that works.  It has to be able to handle the file uploads so I cannot just redirect the response.

I am sure I am just not connecting the dots with some something obvious and I am probably way over complicating it.  Appreciate any help.

Comment: Looks like you have to execute a redirect at the end of the processing.

Comment: @Luiggi I am not sure where to redirect to.  I can't just redirect to the third party and keep the file upload in-tact.

Comment: Yes, in fact looks to be an odd requirement. This isn't a technical problem because it can't be done. You must explain the problems of using a redirect to your superiors (I know that explaining technical stuff to non-developers can be hard, specially for non-software related people).

Comment: Odd requirement as it is, I don't think it is unreasonable.  We want it to appear seamless to the user that expects to end up at the other site.  Seems like there are many use cases where you would want to intercept a form and then send it off to another service.   Also, I have to explain why it cannot be done in java to someone who knows it can be done in PHP with like 2 or 3 lines of code.